# Why does Series give two different results for given function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, series-expansion, parametric-functions

I want to do `Series` of this function `x^12 Cos[y x]^2 Sin[y x]^6 Sin[(-1 + Sqrt[3]) y x]^2` around `{z, 0, 2}` where `x -> (((1 + Sqrt[3]) m π)/(2 y) + z)`. When I do it in general, Mathematica gives the following result which is `Indeterminate`.

```
Series[(x^12 Cos[y x]^2 Sin[y x]^6 Sin[(-1 + Sqrt[3]) y x]^2 ) /. 
   x -> (((1 + Sqrt[3]) m π)/(2 y) + z), {z, 0, 2}] // 
 FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers] &

(* FullSimplify::infd: Expression 2 (-1+Sqrt[3]) y Cos[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[3]) (1+Sqrt[3]) m π] ((3 (1+Sqrt[3])^12 m^12 π^12 Cos[1/2 Plus[<<2>>] m π]^3 Sin[1/2 Plus[<<2>>] m π]^5)/(2048 y^11)+Sin[1/2 Plus[<<2>>] m π]^6 ((3 Plus[<<2>>]^11 m^11 π^11 Cos[<<1>>]^2)/(512 y^11)-(Plus[<<2>>]^12 m^12 π^12 Cos[Times[<<4>>]] Sin[Times[<<4>>]])/(2048 y^11))) Sin[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[3]) (1+Sqrt[3]) m π]+<<1>>+((-1+Sqrt[3])^2 (<<1>>)^12 <<3>> <<1>>^6 (Cos[1/2 <<3>> π]^2-Sin[<<1>>]^2))/(4096 y^10) 
    simplified to Indeterminate. *)
(* Indeterminate z^2+O[z]^3 *)
```

But when I write my function as a product of two functions `x^12` and  `Cos[y x]^2 Sin[y x]^6 Sin[(-1 + Sqrt[3]) y x]^2` and then do the `Series` separately for each of them, I see that the result is not `Indeterminate`.

```
{Series[(x^12) /. x -> (((1 + Sqrt[3]) m π)/(2 y) + z), {z, 0, 2}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers] & , 
 Series[(Cos[y x]^2 Sin[y x]^6 Sin[(-1 + Sqrt[3]) y x]^2 ) /. 
    x -> (((1 + Sqrt[3]) m π)/(2 y) + z), {z, 0, 2}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers] &}

(* {((1+Sqrt[3])^12 m^12 π^12)/(4096 y^12)+(3 (1+Sqrt[3])^11 m^11 π^11 z)/(512 y^11)+(33 (1+Sqrt[3])^10 m^10 π^10 z^2)/(512 y^10)+O[z]^3,-1/2 ((-2+Sqrt[3]) y^2 Sin[Sqrt[3] m π]^2 Sin[1/2 (1+Sqrt[3]) m π]^4) z^2+O[z]^3} *)
```

Where am I going wrong and why are the two results different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = x^12 Cos[y x]^2 Sin[y x]^6 Sin[(-1 + Sqrt[3]) y x]^2;

repl = x -> (((1 + Sqrt[3]) m π)/(2 y) + z);
```

Since [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) also accepts the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html), use an [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) construct so that the assumptions are available to `Series` as well as to [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
method1 = Assuming[m ∈ Integers, Series[expr /. repl, {z, 0, 2}] //
   FullSimplify]
```

[image]

```
method2 = Assuming[m ∈ Integers, Series[expr[[1]] /. repl, {z, 0, 2}]*
    Series[Rest[expr] /. repl, {z, 0, 2}] // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

The two methods produce identical results

```
method1 === method2

(* True *)
```